# How do I include sheet music into application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am asking this question again, and "elaborate" as to what I am trying to convey. What I am trying to do is that I want to program an application that will generate a note in sheet music while matching the sine tone that is being played at the same time. Kind of like flash cards, but with music. What I want to do is avoid adding images to the source folder that way I can keep it small in the matters of storage space

Comment: Yeah, confusing question.  What, if anything, is the input to the app?  Sounds?  "Button" presses on notes?  What do you mean by "generate a note in sheet music"?  Do you mean to effectively generate new sheet music?  Or are you saying that existing sheet music (somehow encoded) will be scanned and played?

Comment: If you're looking for a machine representation of sheet music then MIDI format is probably the most logical choice, if you don't want to invent your own.

Comment: Input would be from the mic, but the thing is it will be comparing the actual frequency declared, with the frequency given by the user.

Comment: So like an instrument "tuner" that can read sheet music.  So basically you need the "tuner" portion, a sheet music reader of some sort, and whatever logic you need to interface with the user and indicate good/bad.  Separating the fundamental frequency of most instruments is relatively easy, but doing it in "real time" is probably a bit more challenging.  (Voice would be more challenging still.)  The sheet music "reader" is relatively simple, save for the fact that you need to synchronize with the input -- correct for timing variations.

Comment: I'd suggest that you break the problem into 8-10 different "tasks" and address them individually, rather than trying to solve everything at once.  First would be the tuner function, for which there are probably some open-source examples on the net.  Then invent your music notation (MIDI is probably overkill for this) and build a simple reader.  Then you will have some ideas about the rest.

Comment: Displaying the music to be played is a very simple part of the whole thing -- individual images of the different duration notes, with your view controller adjusting their position relative to the staff.

Answer (score 0):

There's an "easy" way and a "hard" way, imho.
The "hard" way would involve interfacing with sound card drivers and sending values corresponding to notes along. I'm guessing this approach is over your head a bit (and mine too!).

I would approach it *easier* with pre-recorded sound files.
Have a database of filepaths and whatever musical information you want.
Select a row from the DB, play the file, then compare user input to the actual data.

Sorry this is vague... but so is your question. If you're looking for more information please ask more specifically.